# Is it possible to distribute a chrome extension privately and without the use of the chrome web store?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently creating a chrome extension for the company I work for and I was wondering if there's any way to install the extension in the browsers of my users without having to publish it on the chrome web store. I don't really have any reason for submitting it to the store since we're only gonna be using it in our company and we don't plan on distributing it externally.

I'm having trouble submitting it to the store even, since they need me to write a detailed description of the extensions functions. The problem with that is, that the program really only has one function and that function is very very simple. So I can't make the description any more detailled than it already is now.

I also don't want to use the developer mode, because that'll show my users a warning whenever they restart their browsers...

Can I get some advice please?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at the loading the unpacked version?

Comment: you can only load the unpacked version in developer mode. @MarcusJason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a explanation on how I only want to distribute it in the company I work for to the descriptions. That seems to have satisfied google. :D